# jQuery AJAX function returning strange output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm playing around with AJAX requests to a php file via jQuery, and I'm getting some strange output.

`main.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
        include('main.html');
    ?>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $('#startButton').click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });

        });


    </script>

</body>
```

`test.php`:

```
<?php

    echo 'Hello';

?>
```

Instead of alerting 'Hello' on button click, my program alerts the html of `main.php`. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: random guess redirecting errors to main.php

Comment: Can you show the HTML for your button?

Comment: try setting dataType to text or json

Comment: What happens if you try to load test.php directly in your browser?

Comment: @Trott `<button type='button' id='startButton'>Go!</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - I'm using GoogleAppEngine and my `app.yami` file was not configured to direct requests to `test.php`, as it defaults all requests to `main.php`, hence the returned html.

Apologies for not stating that I was using GAE - I didn't think it was relevant.

Credit to @Dagon for suggesting that it was a redirecting error which led me to the correct answer.